# How to extract type parameter from type

Tags: scala, generics, types

Given the following classes:

```
abstract class Foo[B] 
abstract class Baz[B, F <: Foo[B]] {
    def get(foo: F): B
    // other methods
}
```

I hate that I need two type parameters in `Baz` when the first is redundant.  I want to write something like:

```
abstract class Baz[F <: Foo[B]] {
  def get(foo: F): B
}
```

Is it possible for me to reference the B type (of F) within Baz without taking multiple type parameters?  This feels like it should be possible, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If `F` is context bound to `Foo` that means that an implicit `Foo[F]` must be in scope, which can be accessed via `implicitly [Foo[F]]`.

Comment: I can't seem to get implicitly to work. I've updated my example to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Are you sure you want context bounds? Can you share a more real example an explain your ultimate goal.

Comment: I'm making a game framework. I'm providing an abstract game and an abstract player. Games are context bound to a particular type of players. I have functions that operate on games and its players, but I don't want to take multiple type parameters

Comment: Your question might make more sense if you de-sugared the context bounds. You might try rewriting the classes to the equivalent classes with implicit parameters. As it is, `F: Foo[B]` is **very** different from what you posted originally.

Comment: OK, I thought that context bound simply means "parameterized". I was wrong, and realized that a bunch of my type code is wrong. I think I've updated my question to be more accurate.

Comment: @jwvh does the current iteration make more sense?

Comment: It is possible, but two complex. What is wrong with having both parameters?

Comment: I am forced to pass around 2 parameters everywhere, which I really don't like. Regardless, I'd love to see how it is possible to decide if that is what I actually want to do

Comment: @NathanMerrill Why do you need to pass around the two type parameters? Should type inference help? How are you using this classes, why are them abstract. Do you control both classes? Have you considered using **type members** instead of **type parameters**? Maybe these should be **typeclasses**? - Without more context and a real example is hard to provide a workaround. - But as jwvh said, on the general case, you have to pass both type parameters.

Comment: It's hard to give a concrete example without getting into lots of unnecessary details. It sounds like the answer is "No", so unless I hear anything else, I'll go ahead and accept jwvh's answer

Comment: I'll take a look at those suggestions to see if they will work as alternatives. Thank you!

Comment: @NathanMerrill Actually yes, the answer for this specific question is No, you can not use `B` inside the body of the class without naming it. However, there are ways to avoid to pass the two arguments explicitly, but those are use context dependent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Can you make `B` a type member rather than type parameter?

   ```
   abstract class Foo { type B }
   abstract class Baz[F <: Foo] {
     def get(foo: F): F#B
     // other methods
   }
   ```

   Then if you need both type parameter and type member you can use Aux-pattern

   ```
   abstract class Foo { type B }
   // Foo.Aux[B] instead of Foo[B]
   object Foo {
     type Aux[B0] = Foo { type B = B0 }
   }
   abstract class Baz[F <: Foo] {
     def get(foo: F): F#B
     // other methods
   }
   ```
2. Can you make `F` higher-kinded and `get` polymorphic? <strike>(Looks like sort of "tagless final" approach.)</strike>

   ```
   abstract class Foo[B]
   abstract class Baz[F[X] <: Foo[X]] {
     def get[B](foo: F[B]): B
     // other methods
   }
   ```
3. Can you make `Foo` a type class?

   ```
   abstract class Foo[F] {
     type B
   }
   object Foo {
     type Aux[F, B0] = Foo[F] { type B = B0 }
     def instance[F, B0]: Aux[F, B0] = new Foo[F] { type B = B0 }

     //instead of  class F1 extends Foo[B1]
     implicit val foo1: Aux[F1, B1] = instance
   }

   abstract class Baz[F](implicit val foo: Foo[F]) {
     def get: foo.B
     // other methods
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   abstract class Baz[F: Foo] {
     val foo: Foo[F] = implicitly
     def get: foo.B
     // other methods
   }
   ```
4. Can you extract the two type parameters to a new class?

   ```
   abstract class Foo[B]

   abstract class Tuple {
     type B
     type F <: Foo[B]
   }

   abstract class Baz[T <: Tuple] {
     def get(foo: T#F): T#B
     // other methods
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   abstract class Baz[T <: Tuple](t: T) {
     def get(foo: t.F): t.B
     // other methods
   }
   ```

Comment: Type member worked. I've never really used them before, so I have a new world to explore. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I hate that I need two type parameters in Baz when the first is redundant.

There is no redundancy. If the `Baz` code makes reference to 2 different types then we need to have 2 different names for them (`F` and `B`, or `X` and `Y`, or `THIS` and `THAT`, it doesn't really matter).

If the `Baz` code only makes reference to 1 type, but that type needs to be restricted to something that `Foo` has implemented then you could add that restriction:

```
class Baz[X](implicit ev: Foo[X]) { ...
```

This can be simplified as:

```
class Baz[X: Foo] { ...
```

---

If the types cannot be inferred, and you wish to simplify instance creation, perhaps a type member/alias can be used.

```
abstract class Baz[B] {
  type F = Foo[B]
  def get(foo: F): B
}
```

But it's often clearer just to write things out.

```
abstract class Baz[B] {
  def get(foo: Foo[B]): B
}
```

But this, of course, eliminates the possibility of sub-types.

Comment: My code does reference both F and B types, unfortunately. I'll make that more clear

Comment: It totally is redundant: to create a Baz, I have to declare `Baz[A, B[A]]`.`A` is written there twice, and gives no extra information.

Comment: Yes, the `A` appears redundant in `Baz[A,B[A]]`, but `F <: Foo[B]` means that `F` can be _any_ sub-type of `Foo[B]`. So if `B[Z]` is a sub-type of `B[A]` then `Baz[A,B[Z]]` is permitted.